# mPDF (PHP) does not recognize html check mark

Tags: php, html, mpdf, checkmark

I am showing a table in HTML on my web page where a check mark is shown properly (I am using `&#10004;` for the bold check mark).

I am using classic-asp to display the HTML. The html buildup (tableOutput) is then posted to a PHP script ($output = $_POST["output"]) that uses mPDF.php (version 6.0) to print to PDF the same HTML table and somehow the check mark wont print correctly (%u2714 in printed on my PDF). All the rest of the table is printed correctly, only the check mark has a problem.

I tried adding the Symbola.ttf and Symbola_hint.ttf fonts in the mpdf\ttfonts folder but it didnt do the trick.

**HTML (classic-asp)**:

```
tableOutput = tableOutput & "<TD class='center pass_x' style='font-family:symbola;'>&#10004;</TD>"
```

**PHP** (create_report_pdf.php):

```
$output = $_POST["output"];  //This is the html buildup tableOutput discussed previously
$header = Irrelevant;
$footer= Irrelevant;

$mpdf = new mPDF( 'utf-8', 'A4-L', 0, '', 5, 5, 20, 20);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style,1);
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader( $header );
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter( $footer );
$mpdf->WriteHTML( $output );
$mpdf->Output($temp ,'F' );
```

**config_fonts.php** (I addded symbola.ttf and Symbola_hint.ttf in the mpdf\ttfonts folder):

```
$this->fontdata = array (
        "symbola"  => array (
                'R' => "Symbola.ttf",
                'I' => "Symbola_hint.ttf",
        ),
```

**CSS (PHP $style variable points to create_report_pdf.css)**:

```
.report-table{ 
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 7pt; 
    width: 100%;
} 

th,td{ 
    font-size: 7pt; 
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    vertical-align : middle;
}

.center{ text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }

INPUT{
    border-color:#ffffff !important;
}

.pf{ width: 45px; }
.fix-cell{ width: 90px; }
.dr-column, .dr-input{ width: 100px; }
.comments, .comments-input{ width: 130px; }
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

- Replacing manually the `%u2714` with the respective html entity `&#10004;` by doing the following:

```php
$output = str_replace('%u2714', '&#10004;', $output);
```

- Implement more generic approach that will handle all such special chars. The approach is based on the fact that `%uXXXX` is a non-standard notation scheme for URL-encoding Unicode characters. So you need to convert `%uXXXX` notation to HTML entity notation `&#xXXXX;` and then this can be decoded to actual UTF-8 by html_entity_decode.

```php
$output = preg_replace('/%u([0-9A-F]+)/', '&#x$1;', $output);
$output = html_entity_decode($output, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion ($output = str_replace('%u2714', '&#10004;', $output); ) and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristianCaron I am happy to hear that I have helped you, so can you accept/upvote my answer?